Best location for a heat sink - On top of SMD package IC or bottom of PCB
I have a circuit board with several MOSFETs in TO252 and TO263 packages as well as other IC with exposed pads on the bottom.
I need to cool these parts and have 2 options:

Glue a heat sink directly to the case of the parts.

Create an exposed copper area on the other side of the PCB, below each part and glue the heat sink to there (or solder it if I can find one with that option).


What is better from a thermal perspective?

Why do you only have those two options? And which one is better depends how you are able to actually implement each solution. And to be fair, maybe there is improvement in the circuit, because MOSFETs heat when they dissipate power, so is it possible to improve the circuit or buy better FETs so they don't heat as much. Is this an analog or digital circuit, are the FETs used for switching or lineat mode applications?

You should figure out what amount of cooling is actually necessary before proceeding. Cooling those packages from the top is probably going to have a very small effect and using thermal vias + copper pours on the bottom layer requires lots of space. Better to proceed with concrete numbers rather than have to do a redesign after your prototypes fail (or worse, your shipped products).

The common way is to use a heatsink with thermal gap fill pad on the top or bottom.
If you have varying package heights on the top obtaining a suitable thermal gap filler might be difficult, so the bottom side can be used with thermal via's in the board design.
You may want to fill these via's either with solder or epoxy, ask for the capabilities of your PCB manufacturer and assembly house.
Don't expect extreme cooling improvements, if you need to dissipate lots of watts you're probably better off using TO-220 and TO-247.

Thanks,
So essentially you say there is not much differences to the location of the heat sink in this scenario right?
I can place it either directly on the case or on the underneath exposed pad and it will have the same (almost) effect.
